# Jersey method + call to Hibernate class = My database completly erases it self

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

Good afternoon, 
i would like to know if someone can help.

I have a Jersey method

```
@GET
@Path("/update")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String updateLocal(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException, JSONException{
    //MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters(); 
   // String newAddress = queryParams.getFirst("address");
    //int idOfLocal = new Integer(queryParams.getFirst("id"));

    Local.updateLocal(1, "ldfjslkdfhjh");
    return "test";
}
```

The hibernate method i use is:

```
public static void updateLocal(int id, String newAddress){
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     Local local =  (Local) session.get(Local.class, id);
     Hibernate.initialize(local);

    local.setAddress(newAddress);

    session.save(local);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

for some reason if i call the updateLocal in a normal Java Class it works and produces the result, but if i call it in the web method my database goes into a inconsistency state.

Anyone noes how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could set org.hibernate logging level to DEBUG and try to work out what is going on.

Comment: What is the "inconsistency"? What is erased? What is the result you get, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Thanks :D
The problem was hibernate was in "create" mode. Thanks a lot both of you. I've been using this always in create never remembered to change it.